# How to do cost analysis from start_date to end_date SQL?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am doing expense analysis with Bigquery. I have a table with `start_date`, `end_date`, `expense` and I have to bring the expense to all days in the range between start_date and end_date.
My table looks like:

| Start Date | End Date | Expense code | Amount | Ref_code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/11/2021 | 13/11/2021 | 3000 | 70,000.00 | 3001 |
| 01/11/2021 | 30/11/2021 | 2000 | 3,000.00 | 2005 |

My expectation should be:

| Start Date | End Date | Expense code | Amount | Ref_code | Daily_date | Daily_expense |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/11/2021 | 13/11/2021 | 3000 | 70,000.00 | 3001 | 01/11/2021 | 5384.615385 |
| 01/11/2021 | 13/11/2021 | 3000 | 70,000.00 | 3001 | 02/11/2021 | 5384.615385 |
| 01/11/2021 | 13/11/2021 | 3000 | 70,000.00 | 3001 | 03/11/2021 | 5384.615385 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 01/11/2021 | 13/11/2021 | 3000 | 70,000.00 | 3001 | 13/11/2021 | 5384.615385 |
| 01/11/2021 | 30/11/2021 | 2000 | 3000 | 2005 | 01/11/2021 | 100 |
| 01/11/2021 | 30/11/2021 | 2000 | 3000 | 2005 | 02/11/2021 | 100 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | 30/11/2021 | 100 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select *, 
  round(Amount / (1 + date_diff(End_Date,Start_Date, day)), 2) as Daily_expense
from data, 
unnest(generate_date_array(Start_Date, End_Date)) Daily_date
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]